# How to continuously store Canon EOS 80D images on a computer over WiFi

Tags: canon, wifi, eos-utility

The EOS Utility for Canon cameras allows the transfer of images stored in the Camera to a computer running the EOS Utility over WiFi.  And this EOS Utility can be configured to transfer only those images not already in the destination folder.

The problem I'm experiencing is, in order to effect the transfer, I must manually initiate it from the EOS Utility running on the computer.  This is impractical, as I'm going to be too busy taking pictures and won't have the time to stop shooting and transfer each picture as I am shooting.

Is there a way to automatically transfer the image from the camera to the computer each time a new photo is taken with the camera.  I want to be able to shoot continuously (without screwing around with a computer) and have all the photos taken transferred to the computer over WiFi as I'm taking the pictures.

Comment: Related: [Automatically send raw photos to PC](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/91366/15871) and [How to transfer all my photos from my Canon camera to my iPad mini in wi-fi?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56687/15871) and [Is it practical to transfer thousands of photos via WiFi? What about 4K video?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56687/15871)

Comment: @MichaelClark - your 2nd and 3rd links are the same even though the text is different. They both point to the 2nd post.

Comment: you could use an automation tool like autohotkey to repeatedly init a transfer, maybe just by clicking a button every 30 seconds of whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is!

In EOS utility you can go to live shoot, then you can see a panel that looks a bit like this:

[image]

In this box the bottom-right icon (the one with the laptop and the down facing arrow) will open a menu where you can set how and where the images are downloaded as you shoot!
(Raw files cannot go over Wi-Fi; you should load them on your PC with a card reader for the best result.)